# VirtualBox error: supR3HardenedScreenImage failed on SHELL32.dll

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

On Windows 10, one day VirtualBox will not boot any VMs. Upon checking logs, I got this error:

Fatal error:
supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: supR3HardenedScreenImage failed on 'C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll'

I searched this error on google and found other people with similar issues, such as this:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=66364

However, I want to fix the root cause of this issue instead of using an old version of VirtualBox without the OS verification checks.

Answer (score 2):

I chose to repair the DLL file on my system, using the instructions on this site: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system

Basically, run the Command Prompt as Administrator, then run the following commands:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
```

Then

```
sfc /scannow
```

The DLL files should now be repaired and VirtualBox should work as expected.

Comment: I had the same issue, except with 'C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll'.  This worked.  Thanks!